# Getting Started Template - File in use by another process

Tags: jss, docker, container

So I am doing the walkthrough: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Everything seems to work just fine (the occasional container is unhealthy message) and when everything completes I can see a working instance of Sitecore running in Docker.

However the dotnet watch command runs into issues as soon as I try to make changes to any of the views in the project, I make a change, I get the following when in the logs:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.Compilation.targets(232,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\solution\src\rendering/obj/container/Debug\netcoreapp3
.1\project.Views.dll" to "C:\solution\src\rendering\bin\container\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\project.Views.dll". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'C:\solution\src\rendering\bin\container\Debug\netco
reapp3.1\project.Views.dll' because it is being used by another process.  [C:\solution\src\rendering\RenderingHost.csproj]
```

The build fails as a result and the site no longer works.

I can restart that image, and then the changes appear, but that is not the way its supposed to work...

Any help will be much appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug in Docker Windows.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42803

I can run the rendering host on the Docker host (from Visual Studio or dotnet CLI) as an alternative, then restart the rendering container to test Experience Editor

Thanks to Nick Wesselman for pointing me in the right direction.